# Is there a way to use Azure DevOps Test Plan parameters for each test case as part of automate testing from pipeline?

Tags: c#, powershell

One of my automated testing projects is looking to use parameters under Azure DevOps Test Plan as an input for each test case. After I did my research I cannot find anything that relates to it. All I found is how to use test cases with parameters manually but I need to use it for automation testing.

I checked ADO API documents from version 5.0, 5.1, and 6.0. There is no information talking about how to use parameters automatically. The closest one that I can find from ADO Documents is Result with Parameters. But that is after manual testing not before.

My unit testing code currently reading those test inputs from a .xml file. But I need to read those inputs from ADO->TestPlan->Parameters. I hope anyone can point me in a direction if it is possible to achieve this goal.

```
    public static async void GetTestCase(string pat, int TestPlanID, int TestSuiteID, int TestCaseID)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", pat))));

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("https://dev.azure.com/natescott/E2E-ATF/_apis/test/Plans/"+ TestPlanID +"/suites/"+ TestSuiteID + "/testcases/"+ TestCaseID + "?api-version=6.0-preview.3").Result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("StatusCode: " + response.StatusCode);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("JSON: " + responseBody);
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope I can replace that .xml with Azure DevOps->TestPlan->Parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into defining all my tests in Azure Dev Ops test plans and then using that to automate my test runs.  After alot of investigation I discovered that the focus of the Azure Dev Ops Test Plans feature is to support people coming in with legacy tests from previous versions of TFS where this was a common thing.

[Run Automated Tests from Azure Test Plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops)

This link might help you, but for me this would only make sense to use if we were going to bring over existing test plans etc.  Basically I recommend using an Azure DevOps pipeline to run your tests and write them as Unit tests. This way the results are captured as part of the build pipeline etc.   If you need test plans specifically, hopefully this link will help.

Comment: thanks for your reply, your answer is part of my existing solution, but what I am looking: For example, Test1 -> get test parameters -> get test results -> Base on the prev. test results -> get new test parameters -> Test2 -> get test results -> etc...

Answer (score 0):

Go to ADO-->Test Plans-->Parameters

Step 1 : Create a Shared Parameter set like below 
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk7m0.png)

Step 2 : Go to any of your test case and scroll down and check for Parameter values

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MizqF.png)

Step 3 : Click on that Parameter value and click on add parameters and then select the parameter set you have created as shared parameters.

Step 4 : After invoking the shared parameter set ,now you have to use those parameters in your **test case steps**. For that go to Steps field.

Step 5 : By assigning " **@** " to every parameter . See below Picture.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyFf5.png)

Step 6 : Now you can run your test case and see these parameters and use it efficiently .

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think the method you mentioned above is only for manual testing not for test automation. For example, Test1 -> get test parameters -> get test results -> Base on the prev. test results -> get new test parameters -> etc....

Comment: If you want to GET the test parameters and test results
You can make use of REST API 

Get Test Cases For a Suite.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/{planId}/Suites/{suiteId}/TestCase/{testCaseIds}?api-version=5.1-preview.2

and

Get a test plan by Id.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/testplan/plans/{planId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1

OR go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test%20%20plans?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: yes, but how can you get and pass these parameters dynamically (not hard-code)?

Answer (score 0):

I've found something here. But it seems working only for the manual run.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/parameter%20results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Example:
Request:

```
GET 
https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/fabrikam-fiber-tfvc/_apis/test/Runs/results/Results/{testCaseResultId}/Iterations/{iterationId}/parameterresults?api-version=5.1
    Response:
    {
      "count": 2,
      "value": [
        {
          "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/fabrikam-fiber-tfvc/_apis/test/Runs/4/Results/100000/Iterations/1/ParameterResults?paramName=username",
          "iterationId": 1,
          "actionPath": "00000002",
          "parameterName": "username",
          "value": "abc"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/fabrikam-fiber-tfvc/_apis/test/Runs/4/Results/100000/Iterations/1/ParameterResults?paramName=password",
          "iterationId": 1,
          "actionPath": "00000003",
          "parameterName": "password",
          "value": "new"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Test Case it's a work item type, so you can use the [Get Work Item Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP) to get the parameters:
GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=7.2-preview.3](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/wit/workitems/%7Bid%7D?api-version=7.2-preview.3)

Or Directly you can use
GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?fields=Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Parameters&api-version=7.2-preview.3](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/wit/workitems/%7Bid%7D?fields=Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Parameters&api-version=7.2-preview.3)